# Whats the Mercurial hg clone syntax to clone a repository to a folder on a local file system

Tags: mercurial, clone

Whats the Mercurial hg clone syntax to clone a repository to a folder on a local file system. Say I have a repository in `C:\MyProject\` and I want to create a clone in `G:\Version Control\MyProject\` - what would the command line be?

Thanks

Answer (score 53, accepted):

`hg help` is your friend.  `hg help clone` yields:

> hg clone [OPTION]... SOURCE [DEST]

So, for this case it should be something like:

```
hg clone C:\MyProject "G:\Version Control\MyProject"
```

Comment: Thanks, That worked. I didn't read the hg help carefully enough.

Comment: Suppose user want to clone to a different system in the same network , then what will be the command ?